# Unable to get Entry Value in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

I am using Python 2.7.
I was unable to print the value of the `Entry` (textbox).

```
import Tkinter

gui = Tkinter.Tk();
tb = Tkinter.Entry(gui,bd =10);
tb.pack();
tv = tb.get();
def printv() :
    print tv;
b =Tkinter.Button(gui,text="Aj",command =printv);
b.pack();
gui.mainloop();
```

Comment: Take a look at the example in the link, and/or add a print statement after the get() to show that you are getting before anything is entered. http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_entry_widgets.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you are calling `tb.get()` at the wrong time. You need to call it *after* the user clicks the button, not before. Or more correctly, during processing of the button event:

```
def printv():
    value = tb.get()
    print value
```

(note: semicolons as statement terminators aren't required in python)